# rsync permission denied when using rsync:// protocol between ubuntu servers

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync a file from host2 to host1 (both running Ubuntu Server 20.04) without having to type any password, using the `rsync://` protocol.

#### on host2:

```
$ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock

[folder]
    path = /home/username
    comment = rsync folder
    read only = false
    list = yes
```

Then I run `sudo systemctl start rsync`

```
$ cat /var/log/rsyncd.log 
2021/03/25 01:07:51 [8035] rsyncd version 3.1.3 starting, listening on port 873
```

#### on host1:

```
$ rsync /home/username/test.txt rsync://host2:/folder
rsync: mkstemp "/.test.txt.UHerWZ" (in folder) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

#### on host2:

```
$ tail -F /var/log/rsyncd.log
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] name lookup failed for host1: Name or service not known
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] connect from UNKNOWN (host1)
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] rsync to folder/ from UNKNOWN (host1)
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] receiving file list
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] rsync: mkstemp "/.test.txt.KRLgUO" (in folder) failed: Permission denied (13)
2021/03/25 03:13:00 [9212] sent 122 bytes  received 95 bytes  total size 5
```

What is causing the permission to be denied? Am I required to define a username and password in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when rsyncd runs as root, it changes to user `nobody` before doing transfers. If your path `/home/username` is not owned by this id, and so on, you will get errors. Typically, you need to add an id to run as in your stanza (and usually also set the group id to the defaults for that user) as follows:

```
[folder]
    path = /home/username
    uid = username
    gid = *
    ...
```